# MySql with GoogleAppEngine connection failed?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

I have created an application using java with mysql. It's run successfully in local. when i deployed my application into **GOOGLE APP ENGINE** Its build Successfully and runs an hour.

After an hour, Connection has been failed automatically. Is there any configuration is missing my google app engine?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the limitation of the engine or maybe of the free version. While going through the docs I found this:

**App Engine Limits**

Requests from App Engine applications to Cloud SQL are subject to the following time and connection limits:

1. For apps running in the App Engine standard environment, all database requests must finish within the HTTP request timer, around 60 seconds. For apps running in the flexible environment, all database requests must finish within 60 minutes.
2. Offline requests like cron tasks have a time limit of 10 minutes.
3. Requests to Cloud SQL have limitations based on the scaling type of the App Engine module and how long an instance can remain in memory (residence).
4. Each App Engine instance running in a standard environment cannot have more than 60 concurrent connections to a Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Eventhough I am using a paid version of  **GOOGLE APP ENGINE**. Still i faced the same issue .

Comment: Could be the limitation of the engine then, irrespective of the version.